# Computing Integral of a Complex Modulus

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I go about computing this integral?

$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \! |{\cos(2 x) + i \sin(2 x)}| \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

I know that the value of it is
$$
{2 \pi}
$$

But am unsure of how to compute it due to the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming $x\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\int\left|\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)i\right|\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{\left(\cos(2x)\right)^2+\left(\sin(2x)\right)^2}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{\cos^2(2x)+\sin^2(2x)}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(4x)+1\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos(4x)\right)}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cos(4x)+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(4x)}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\cos(4x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(4x)+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{0+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{\frac{2}{2}}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\sqrt{1}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int 1\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$x+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $|x + yi| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

By the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, the modulus of $\cos 2x + i\sin 2x$ is therefore $1$.